# Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]. Java do not know why

Tags: java

Hi I recently started computer programming in java, I have recently been  writing up a Bank Account program for school but I keep getting this
Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]. I've looked for an answer on this website, but do not know how to implement it. here's my code. (I'm using Dr. Java as Workspace/Compiler) `

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankAccount {

  private Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
  private String name;
  private double balance;

  public BankAccount() {
    String n = "";
    double b = 0.0;
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    n = in.nextLine();
    // check for null string
    if(!n.equals("")) {
      name = n;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter your current balance: ");
    // ToDo: add a check for input
    b = in.nextDouble();
    balance = b;
  }

  public void deposit() {
    System.out.println("Enter the amount you would like to deposit: ");
    double deposit = in.nextDouble();
    if(deposit > 0.0){
      balance = balance + deposit;
    }
  }

  public void withdraw() {
    System.out.println("Enter the amount you would like to withdraw: ");
    double withdraw = in.nextDouble();
    if(withdraw > 0.0 && withdraw <= balance){
      balance = balance - withdraw;
    }
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }
}
```

Please can someone help?

Edit: If people didn't understand me, This is project for school that I'm working on, Here is the assignment

> A bank account shall have an owner’s name (e.g., Jane Doe), and a current balance as 
>   attributes. It shall also have methods to set/get the owner’s name, to make a deposit, to make 
>   a withdrawal, and to get the current balance. When an account object is crea
>   ted, it must have 
>   an owner’s name or an owner’s name and an initial deposit. If an account is created with just an 
>   owner’s name, it shall have a balance of zero. Withdrawals cannot be made for more than an 
>   account’s current balance. If an attempt is made t
>   o withdraw more than the current balance a 
>   message shall be displayed indicating that the withdrawal is disallowed. Develop the code for 
>   this class and name the class 
>   Account
>   .
>   Write a program that uses the 
>   Account
>   class. The program shall create two 
>   Accoun
>   t
>   objects, 
>   one that is created with only an owner’s name and one that is created with an owner’s name 
>   and an opening deposit amount. 
>   The program shall display the account balances after each 
>   account is created. 
>   The program shall make two deposits and two w
>   ithdrawals from each 
>   account.
>   The account balances after each transaction shall be displayed.

Also it may kind of sound dumb, but I'm a complete noob at programming there maybe an error that's obvious, but I'm maybe not able to see it, please point out to me my errors.

Comment: You can improve your question by adding what your program is supposed to do. What is the expected result? What do you want to happen when you start the program?

Comment: The error message is correct, and perfectly clear. What part of it don't you understand?